# How i can externalize a function from a prototype in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, prototype

I'm trying to hack/personalize a html5/ajax/javascript [plugin for drag&drop and upload a file](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/html5-ajax-file-upload/) 
(the problem with this plugin is that it uploads the file directly after being dropped on the drop zone..) So i want to change this behaviour and control the moment in which the upload should happens
(the upload uses jquery-ajax) by externalizing the upload function

The main plugin's script is written in this page (the html5Upload.js) :

```
   /*jslint unparam: true, browser: true, devel: true */
/*global define*/

define(function () {
    'use strict';

    var module = {},
        noop = function () { },
        console = window.console || { log: noop },
        supportsFileApi;

    function UploadManager(options) {
        var self = this;
        self.dropContainer = options.dropContainer;
        self.inputField = options.inputField;
        self.uploadsQueue = [];
        self.activeUploads = 0;
        self.data = options.data;
        self.key = options.key;
        self.maxSimultaneousUploads = options.maxSimultaneousUploads || -1;
        self.onFileAdded = options.onFileAdded || noop;
        self.uploadUrl = options.uploadUrl;
        self.onFileAddedProxy = function (upload) {
            console.log('Event: onFileAdded, file: ' + upload.fileName);
            self.onFileAdded(upload);
        };

        self.initialize();
    }

    function FileUpload(file) {
        var self = this;

        self.file = file;
        self.fileName = file.name;
        self.fileSize = file.size;
        self.uploadSize = file.size;
        self.uploadedBytes = 0;
        self.eventHandlers = {};
        self.events = {
            onProgress: function (fileSize, uploadedBytes) {
                var progress = uploadedBytes / fileSize * 100;
                console.log('Event: upload onProgress, progress = ' + progress + ', fileSize = ' + fileSize + ', uploadedBytes = ' + uploadedBytes);
                (self.eventHandlers.onProgress || noop)(progress, fileSize, uploadedBytes);
            },
            onStart: function () {
                console.log('Event: upload onStart');
                (self.eventHandlers.onStart || noop)();
            },
            onCompleted: function (data) {
                console.log('Event: upload onCompleted, data = ' + data);
                file = null;
                (self.eventHandlers.onCompleted || noop)(data);
            }
        };
    }

    FileUpload.prototype = {
        on: function (eventHandlers) {
            this.eventHandlers = eventHandlers;
        }
    };

    UploadManager.prototype = {

        initialize: function () {
            console.log('Initializing upload manager');
            var manager = this,
                dropContainer = manager.dropContainer,
                inputField = manager.inputField,
                cancelEvent = function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                };

            if (dropContainer) {
                manager.on(dropContainer, 'dragover', cancelEvent);
                manager.on(dropContainer, 'dragenter', cancelEvent);
                manager.on(dropContainer, 'drop', function (e) {
                    cancelEvent(e);
                    manager.processFiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
                });
            }

            if (inputField) {
                manager.on(inputField, 'change', function () {
                    manager.processFiles(this.files);
                });
            }
        },

        processFiles: function (files) {
            console.log('Processing files: ' + files.length);
            var manager = this,
                len = files.length,
                file,
                upload,
                i;

            for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
                file = files[i];
                if (file.size === 0) {
                    alert('Files with files size zero cannot be uploaded or multiple file uploads are not supported by your browser');
                    break;
                }

                upload = new FileUpload(file);
                manager.uploadFile(upload);
            }
        },

        uploadFile: function (upload) {
            var manager = this;

            manager.onFileAdded(upload);

            // Queue upload if maximum simultaneous uploads reached:
            if (manager.activeUploads === manager.maxSimultaneousUploads) {
                console.log('Queue upload: ' + upload.fileName);
                manager.uploadsQueue.push(upload);
                return;
            }

            manager.ajaxUpload(upload);
        },

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // This is the function i want to externalize to be called from outside this script
        ajaxUpload: function (upload) {
            var manager = this,
                xhr,
                formData,
                fileName,
                file = upload.file,
                prop,
                data = manager.data,
                key = manager.key || 'file';

            console.log('Beging upload: ' + upload.fileName);
            manager.activeUploads += 1;

            xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            formData = new window.FormData();
            fileName = file.name;

            xhr.open('POST', manager.uploadUrl);

            // Triggered when upload starts:
            xhr.upload.onloadstart = function () {
                // File size is not reported during start!
                console.log('Upload started: ' + fileName);
                upload.events.onStart();
            };

            // Triggered many times during upload:
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function (event) {
                if (!event.lengthComputable) {
                    return;
                }

                // Update file size because it might be bigger than reported by the fileSize:
                upload.events.onProgress(event.total, event.loaded);
            };

            // Triggered when upload is completed:
            xhr.onload = function (event) {
                console.log('Upload completed: ' + fileName);

                // Reduce number of active uploads:
                manager.activeUploads -= 1;

                upload.events.onCompleted(event.target.responseText);

                // Check if there are any uploads left in a queue:
                if (manager.uploadsQueue.length) {
                    manager.ajaxUpload(manager.uploadsQueue.shift());
                }
            };

            // Triggered when upload fails:
            xhr.onerror = function () {
                console.log('Upload failed: ', upload.fileName);
            };

            // Append additional data if provided:
            if (data) {
                for (prop in data) {
                    if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                        console.log('Adding data: ' + prop + ' = ' + data[prop]);
                        formData.append(prop, data[prop]);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Append file data:
            formData.append(key, file);

            // Initiate upload:
            xhr.send(formData);
        },

        on: function (element, eventName, handler) {
            if (!element) {
                return;
            }
            if (element.addEventListener) {
                element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
            } else if (element.attachEvent) {
                element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, handler);
            } else {
                element['on' + eventName] = handler;
            }
        }
    };

    module.fileApiSupported = function () {
        if (typeof supportsFileApi !== 'boolean') {
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute("type", "file");
            supportsFileApi = !!input.files;
        }

        return supportsFileApi;
    };

    module.initialize = function (options) {
        return new UploadManager(options);
    };

    return module;
});
```

i was thinking about to set the scope of  all variables needed by that function to the global scope
and define it outside the prototype .. i'm not sure it will work as this function calls the manager to which it belongs itself..

honnestly, i'm not that expert to make this work , i hope your help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said, setting the variables's scope needed by the function to the global scope

```
 var monmanager;
 var monupload;


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*jslint unparam: true, browser: true, devel: true */
/*global define*/

define(function () {
    'use strict';

    var module = {},
        noop = function () { },
        console = window.console || { log: noop },
        supportsFileApi;

    function UploadManager(options) {
        var self = this;
        self.dropContainer = options.dropContainer;
        self.inputField = options.inputField;
        self.uploadsQueue = [];
        self.activeUploads = 0;
        self.data = options.data;
        self.key = options.key;
        self.maxSimultaneousUploads = options.maxSimultaneousUploads || -1;
        self.onFileAdded = options.onFileAdded || noop;
        self.uploadUrl = options.uploadUrl;
        self.onFileAddedProxy = function (upload) {
            console.log('Event: onFileAdded, file: ' + upload.fileName);
            self.onFileAdded(upload);
        };

        self.initialize();
    }

    function FileUpload(file) {
        var self = this;

        self.file = file;
        self.fileName = file.name;
        self.fileSize = file.size;
        self.uploadSize = file.size;
        self.uploadedBytes = 0;
        self.eventHandlers = {};
        self.events = {
            onProgress: function (fileSize, uploadedBytes) {
                var progress = uploadedBytes / fileSize * 100;
                console.log('Event: upload onProgress, progress = ' + progress + ', fileSize = ' + fileSize + ', uploadedBytes = ' + uploadedBytes);
                (self.eventHandlers.onProgress || noop)(progress, fileSize, uploadedBytes);
            },
            onStart: function () {
                console.log('Event: upload onStart');
                (self.eventHandlers.onStart || noop)();
            },
            onCompleted: function (data) {
                console.log('Event: upload onCompleted, data = ' + data);
                file = null;
                (self.eventHandlers.onCompleted || noop)(data);
            }
        };
    }

    FileUpload.prototype = {
        on: function (eventHandlers) {
            this.eventHandlers = eventHandlers;
        }
    };

    UploadManager.prototype = {

        initialize: function () {
            console.log('Initializing upload manager');
            var manager = this,
                dropContainer = manager.dropContainer,
                inputField = manager.inputField,
                cancelEvent = function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                };

            if (dropContainer) {
                manager.on(dropContainer, 'dragover', cancelEvent);
                manager.on(dropContainer, 'dragenter', cancelEvent);
                manager.on(dropContainer, 'drop', function (e) {
                    cancelEvent(e);
                    manager.processFiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
                });
            }

            if (inputField) {
                manager.on(inputField, 'change', function () {
                    manager.processFiles(this.files);
                });
            }
        },

        processFiles: function (files) {
            console.log('Processing files: ' + files.length);
            var manager = this,
                len = files.length,
                file,
                upload,
                i;

            for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
                file = files[i];
                if (file.size === 0) {
                    alert('Files with files size zero cannot be uploaded or multiple file uploads are not supported by your browser');
                    break;
                }

                upload = new FileUpload(file);
                manager.uploadFile(upload);
            }
        },

        uploadFile: function (upload) {
            var manager = this;

            //////////my modification////////////////-----------------------------------------<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            monmanager = manager;
            //////////////////////////-----------------------------------------<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            manager.onFileAdded(upload);

            // Queue upload if maximum simultaneous uploads reached:
            if (manager.activeUploads === manager.maxSimultaneousUploads) {
                console.log('Queue upload: ' + upload.fileName);
                manager.uploadsQueue.push(upload);
                return;
            }

            //////////my modification////////////////-----------------------------------------<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            monupload = upload;
            //////////////////////////-----------------------------------------<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
//            manager.ajaxUpload(upload);
        },

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // This is the function i want to externalize to be called from outside this script
        ajaxUpload: function (upload) {
            var manager = this,
                xhr,
                formData,
                fileName,
                file = upload.file,
                prop,
                data = manager.data,
                key = manager.key || 'file';

            console.log('Beging upload: ' + upload.fileName);
            manager.activeUploads += 1;

            xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            formData = new window.FormData();
            fileName = file.name;

            xhr.open('POST', manager.uploadUrl);

            // Triggered when upload starts:
            xhr.upload.onloadstart = function () {
                // File size is not reported during start!
                console.log('Upload started: ' + fileName);
                upload.events.onStart();
            };

            // Triggered many times during upload:
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function (event) {
                if (!event.lengthComputable) {
                    return;
                }

                // Update file size because it might be bigger than reported by the fileSize:
                upload.events.onProgress(event.total, event.loaded);
            };

            // Triggered when upload is completed:
            xhr.onload = function (event) {
                console.log('Upload completed: ' + fileName);

                // Reduce number of active uploads:
                manager.activeUploads -= 1;

                upload.events.onCompleted(event.target.responseText);

                // Check if there are any uploads left in a queue:
                if (manager.uploadsQueue.length) {
                    manager.ajaxUpload(manager.uploadsQueue.shift());
                }
            };

            // Triggered when upload fails:
            xhr.onerror = function () {
                console.log('Upload failed: ', upload.fileName);
            };

            // Append additional data if provided:
            if (data) {
                for (prop in data) {
                    if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                        console.log('Adding data: ' + prop + ' = ' + data[prop]);
                        formData.append(prop, data[prop]);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Append file data:
            formData.append(key, file);

            // Initiate upload:
            xhr.send(formData);
        },

        on: function (element, eventName, handler) {
            if (!element) {
                return;
            }
            if (element.addEventListener) {
                element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
            } else if (element.attachEvent) {
                element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, handler);
            } else {
                element['on' + eventName] = handler;
            }
        }
    };

    module.fileApiSupported = function () {
        if (typeof supportsFileApi !== 'boolean') {
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute("type", "file");
            supportsFileApi = !!input.files;
        }

        return supportsFileApi;
    };

    module.initialize = function (options) {
        return new UploadManager(options);
    };

    return module;
});
```

and then i could call the function from outside :

```
$("#testcontrol").click(function(){
        console.log( "it's clicked !" );

        monmanager.ajaxUpload(monupload);

    });
```

now it's fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply set it to where it returns whatever it is you need in the global scope. For example,

Instead of:

```
return module;
```

Do:

```
return {
  module: module,
  fileUpload: FileUpload };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the text `define` and replace it with `var uploader =` this will give you an object with all of the characteristics and methods including the one you are looking to extract. Now if this code is relying on some other externally defined object it might through some errors but a basic reading of the code doesn't appear to rely on anything. I would not change the scope of the variables or attempt to  cut out one (or even a few) methods. JavaScript closures make removing arbitrary code much harder.